# Thread safe, concurrent bluetoothLE using TinyB

Tags: java, concurrency, bluetooth, thread-safety, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is a lot of info about Android BluetoothLE programming, but I am working on the design of a small bluetoothLE application using TinyB ([github page](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb), [Java documentation](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/tinyb/java/annotated.html)), which has a similar API to the Android BluetoothLE library.

I am new to concurrent programming in Java, and have read a couple chapters here and there about best practices. What I am unsure of, though, is best practices for handling multiple bluetooth connections.

In order to connect a device, the procedure is fairly simple:

```
// Get the bluetooth manager and start discovery
BluetoothManager manager = BluetoothManager.getBluetoothManager().startDiscovery();



BluetoothDevice device = null ;
List<BluetoothDevice> list = manager.getDevices() ; 

for(Bluetooth device : list){
    // find your device based on what address you're looking for
}

// find the GATT service and characteristic you want to write to
BluetoothGattService tempService = getService(device, "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
BluetoothGattCharacteristic tempValue = getCharacteristic(tempService, "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");

// write to the characteristic
byte[] config = {0x01} ;
tempValue.writeValue(config) ;
```

This code was taken mostly from [Intel-iot-devkit's hello TinyB](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/blob/master/examples/java/HelloTinyB.java)

So this is great for connecting to one device at a time. For multiple connections, I suppose I could have an `ExecutorService` to run the task of creating a connection, or to pair, but what if multiple threads try to use the `BluetoothManager` at the same time? Is this permittable or should the `BluetoothManager` be synchronized?

****EDIT****

Shame on me for not reading the comments to the program I was referencing, but apparently there can only be one reference to BluetoothManager a time.